# Javascript on Google Sites

Tags: javascript, html, google-sites

I am a bit new to the coding. I tried to put javascript on my google site in an HTML box but it is not working. I am pasting my code here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display an alert box:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It should validate with the alert box. The code is running fine when I am running it on the localhost but is not working when I am pasting it in the HTML box within a google site. my company is using Google gadget to make the HTML and javascript run over the google site. Is there any simpler way to do without google gadget?

Answer (score 0):

You can program a div with a method to act like the alert method.  Stylize and position it however you want, but here is an example of one I called msgBox that takes a message and a type (just changes the color for critical, warning, and info) and shows up like a banner at the top of the document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .msgBox{position:absolute;width:50%;top:0px;left:-25%;margin-left:50%;padding:1%;color:black;display:none;font-family:"Calibri","Arial",sans-serif;vertical-align:middle;}
  .info{background-color:rgba(120,170,250,0.95);}
  .warn{background-color:rgba(240,230,120,0.95);}
  .crit{background-color:rgba(250,120,120,0.95);}
  .msgBoxMessage{width:98%;max-width:98%;height:100%;color:black;font-size:1.8vw;vertical-align:middle;}
  .msgBoxClose{height:100%;color:black;font-weight:bold;font-size:3vw;cursor:pointer;transition:0.2s;vertical-align:middle;}
  .msgBoxClose:hover{color:white;transition:0.2s;}
</style>
<script>
  function msgBox(message, type) {
    var msgBox = document.getElementById("msgBox");
    var msgBoxMessage = document.getElementById("msgBoxMessage");
    msgBoxMessage.innerHTML = message;
    msgBox.style.display="block";
    msgBox.className="msgBox " + type.toLowerCase();
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>This page shows how to drive messages without using javascript alert.</h2>
<div class="msgBox info" id="msgBox">
  <table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
      <td class="msgBoxMessage" id="msgBoxMessage"></td>
      <td class="msgBoxClose" onclick="document.getElementById('msgBox').style.display='none';">&times;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<button onclick="msgBox('This is for your <u>information</u>.', 'info');">Info</button>
<button onclick="msgBox('This is just a <i>warning</i>.', 'warn');">Warn</button>
<button onclick="msgBox('This is a <b>critical</b> message!', 'crit');">Crit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you shouldn't be pasting the `<html>` and `<body>` tags in the widget box, as it is already part of a html document.

Simply try this instead:

```
<button onclick="alert('I am an alert box!');">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Thank you sameul for you reply. i tried to run your code by removing my script and <html> and <body> tags..still not running

Comment: i apologize it is a company website thats why i cannot paste alink here..google has accepted the code without the <html> and <body> tags..but no action is taking place as you press the "TRY IT" button